# Redirecting to other page Only once using cookies

Tags: javascript, html

The purpose is to alert the user by redirecting to a warning page but only once.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var location = "https://mysitedotcom";
    var alerted = localStorage.getItem('alerted') || '';
    if (alerted != 'yes') {
    localStorage.setItem('alerted','yes');
    window.location.replace(location);
    </script>
```

However, it seems like I am getting an infinite loop redirecting to index of the site. Is there something I am missing>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you are missing the closing brace for the if, I will assume you just missed it when pasting the code.
What the problem is, is that you are declaring `location` with `var` in the global scope, but there already is one, the browser's native `location` variable with the location info, if you assign that to a url string it will redirect to that url. So the only thing you need to do is change the variable name, the rest of the code should work just fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var newLocation = "https://mysitedotcom";
  var alerted = localStorage.getItem('alerted') || '';
  if (alerted != 'yes') {
    localStorage.setItem('alerted','yes');
    window.location.replace(newLocation);
  }
</script>
```